# Is it possible to publish the original WSDL in the Glassfish 3.1 WebServices?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, glassfish, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I started with a WSDL and used wsimport to generate the Java artificats. Then I implemented the WebService and deployed it to a glassfish 3.1. The glassfish takes the java elements and regenerates a wsdl from these elements.

Can I convince the glassfish to publish the original wsdl to the world, instead of the 'reengineered' ones? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy. But for those, who stumble over this question, I will answer it by myself.

We used the wsdlLocation attribute to convince glassfish to distibute the original wsdl file and not the regenerated one from the java classes.

```
@WebService(name = "wsName", targetNamespace = "http://ws.unknown.com/",
        serviceName="wsServiceName", portName="wsPortName",
        wsdlLocation="wsDefinition.wsdl")
```